# Accessing lru_cache internal dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, memoization

I recently came across the `functools` decorators `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` and `@cache` (in Python 3.9) for "Memoizing" hashable parameters coming into a function.

This has effectively reduced the computation time of my code significantly, so I am keeping these decorators and workflow.

According to the documentation, you get two functions as part of your wrapper: `cache_info()` and `cache_clear()`. The first one gives you information about number of hits and misses in the cache. I haven't had any luck, however, figuring out the parameters that have been stored in the cache.

Is that information available somewhere?

Basically

```py
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def aCachedFunction(hasable_parameter):
    # some operations
    return retValue
```

Is there a way to get the `retValue` of a given parameter, or the cached `hashable_parameters` from the cache in a dict-like structure?

Something like

```py
cachedParameters = aCachedFunction.cache_dict.keys()

hashable_parameter = "hello"
retValue = aCachedFunction.cache_dict[hashable_parameter]
```

Unless parameters are stored with their `hash()`, I guess that structure HAS to be somewhere, right? I can't find it.

Comment: you can get path to this module with `functools.__file__` and then you can see source code. You can even copy source code and change it to get what you need.

Comment: I second the advice to read the source. There are comments explaining why the internals are encapsulated. The cache itself has two implementations. A dict for unlimited size and a linked list for limited size cache.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at the source.